# Form validation using js conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

While validation of form using java script, If user will not enter any info and press enter button then it will show red border to drop down list.But after enter this info it is showing red box again.Please help me to come out from this problem.

```
if(qty_val > 0)
{
    if(jq(this).val() == "Choose One" || jq(this).val() == "Please Select if Ordering" || jq(this).val() == "Please Choose Color" )
    {
        var errorMsg = attr_name.replace("vwattr"+attr_nbr+"_",""); 
        alert("Please select proper "+errorMsg+" in related Items");
        jq(this).css("border", "1px solid red").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your form html here so i have a better idea. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to add and remove class (i.e. `has-error`) on the elements, so you can retain the earlier setting of it by just removing the class. Simplified Example:

CSS:

```
.has-error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#test').click( function() {
    if($('#myinput').val() == "Write Something") {
        $('#myinput').addClass('has-error');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#myinput').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

See simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/daLdmgub/